# h1 title not working in 992px and up media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I've created a web site, and thought I was pretty much done, when suddenly the `h1` title stopped working on the 992px and up media query. I can't figure out what I did to cause this. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kcloyd/3cgbu7nd/ . My first time here, so please excuse me if I didn't enter everything correctly. I will fix if you let me know what else to do.

```
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

html{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box;

}


body {
  display: grid;
  margin: 30px 30px;
  color: #595959;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: url(images/sparkles-background-big.png) no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh; /* Avoid the IE 10-11 `min-height` bug. */
}


img {
    max-width: 100%;
}



.top-nav-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'logo name space burger-links';
    grid-template-columns: 150px auto auto 60px;
}

 #logo  {
   display: grid;
   grid-area: logo; 
   height: 100px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
}


#name {
   display: grid;
   grid-area: name;
   
   margin-top: 25px;
   margin-left: 30px;
    height: 100px;
}

h1 {
  
  font-size: 5vw; 
   font-family:'Shadows Into Light Two';
   letter-spacing: 5px;
  
}

.burger-container {
    display: grid; 
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}   
    
.burger {
    display: grid;
    cursor: pointer; 
}
    
.burger div {
    width: 70px;
    height: 7px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #aa1226;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.burger-links {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: burger-links;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0px;
    max-height: 30vh;
   
    background-color: rgba(243, 243, 243, 0.85);
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    list-style: none;

}
  
.burger-links li {
    display: grid;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}

  
.burger-links a {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #aa1226;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #595959;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}  

.burger-links :last-child a {
    border: none;
}
 
#big-nav {
    display: none;
}
    

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
  
@keyframes navLinkFade {
from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
}
to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}
.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px);
}
   
.main {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'group-pic'
        'gigs';
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
}

.group-pic {
    grid-area: group-pic;
}

.main .group-pic {
    display: grid;
}

.gigs {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: gigs;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1); 
    box-shadow: 3px 5px #efebeb;
     
}

.gigs h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: grey;
    padding-left: 35px;
}
 
.gigs li {
    display: grid;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}

.gigs a {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: grey;
}

   
footer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'copyright  facebook';
    grid-template-columns: 70% 30%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}
    
 #copyright {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: copyright;
    padding-left: 70px;
}
    
 #copyright, h3 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;  
}
    
 #facebook-icon  {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: facebook;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

#facebook-icon img {
    max-height: 100px
}

/* ABOUT */

.mainAbout #band {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#band {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1); 
    box-shadow: 3px 5px #efebeb;
}

.bandTitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    
}

.aboutLists  {
    font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: 600;
}


.aboutPara {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}


/* CONTACT */

.mainContact {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 450px;
}

#contact {
  
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1); 
    box-shadow: 3px 5px #efebeb;
    text-align: center;
  
}

.contactTitle {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 600;
 
}


.contactPara {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 34px;
}

/* MUSIC */


.mainMusic {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}

#video {
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

    
    /* GIGS */

.mainGigs {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'gigs'
        'gigs-pic';
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
}
    
.mainGigs #gigsBox {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: gigs;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1); 
    box-shadow: 3px 5px #efebeb; 
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

    
 #gigsBox li {
  
     list-style-type: none;
}

.mainGigs #gigsBox h3 {
  
    padding-left: 30px;
}
  
.mainGigs img {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: gigs-pic;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}


/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.burger-links {
    height: 25vh;
    top: 10vh;
} 
    
.burger-links a {
    font-size: 24px;
    
} 

    
}


  /* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.burger-links {
    height: 25vh;
    top: 10vh;
    
}
    
.burger-links a {
    font-size: 24px;
    
} 
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.burger-links {
    height: 65vh;
    top: 20vh;
    padding: 1em 1em;
}
    

}



/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    
body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: url(images/sparkles-background-big.png) no-repeat; 
    
}
    
.top-nav-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'logo name space burger-links';
    grid-template-columns: 160px auto auto auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
   
.top-nav-container #logo  {
    height: 100px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#name {
   margin-top: 25px;
   margin-left: 30px;
}

h1 {
   font-size: 5vw; 
}
 
#big-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: justify;
    min-width: 500px;
}
    
#big-nav li {
    display: inline-block; 
    padding-right: 40px
} 
    
#big-nav:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  
}
   
#big-nav li a {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #aa1226;
    transition:  0.25s;
}

#big-nav a {
    opacity:1;
        
}
    
#big-nav a:hover {
    opacity:0.51;
        
}
    
.burger-container {
    display: none;
}
    
.burger-container {
    display: none;
}
    

.main {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

    
.stoneys2 {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 5px 6px rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.3);
}

.gigs {
    display: none;
}

    
.mainAbout #band {
    max-width: 800px;
}
    
.mainContact {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}     

#contact {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
  
footer {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
    
#facebook-icon  {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: facebook;
    padding-left: 200px;
}    
  
.mainMusic {
     display: flex;
     max-width: 1350px;
}   
  
#iframeHolder1, #iframeHolder2 {
     flex: 1;
     padding-right: 20px;
}
    
.mainGigs {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'gigs'
        'gigs-pic';
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;    
}
    
.mainGigs  #gigsBox {
    display: grid;
    grid-area: gigs;
    background-color: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.1); 
    box-shadow: 3px 5px #efebeb; 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
    
.mainGigs, #gigsbox, h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #595959;
    padding-left: 55px;
}
    
.mainGigs, #gigsbox, a {
    font-size: 26px;
}
    
.group-pic {
    grid-area: gigs-pic;
}
  
.main .group-pic {
    display: grid;
}
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    

<head>
    <title>Sycamore Alley</title>
    
    <!-- Normalize.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
    
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    
    <meta name="description" content="Sycamore Alley Band website.">
    
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
   

</head>

<body>
    
    <div class='top-nav-container'>
  
       <a href="index.html">                
         <img src="images/tree-w-sparkles.png" alt="picture of sycamore tree" id="logo">  
       </a>
        
         <h1 id='name'><a href='index.html'>Sycamore Alley</a></h1>
       
    
            <div class='link-wrapper'>        
           
                <ul id='big-nav'>
                    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="music.html">listen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gigs.html">gigs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                
             </div>
                  
              <div class='burger-container'>
               
                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
               
                <ul class='burger-links'>
                    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>   
                    <li><a href="music.html">listen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gigs.html">gigs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                  
                </div>  
                   
                  </div><!-- top-nav-container-->
       
<script src='script.js'></script>
  
        <main class='main'>
 
             
            <img src='images/stoneys%20w%20bar.png' class='group-pic' alt='picture of sycamore alley bandmembers'>
    
            <div class="gigs">
                <h3>gigs</h3>
                    <ul>

                        <li><a href='http://themarketatlibertyplace.com/'> <b>Market at Liberty Place&#126;</b><br>Kennett Square PA<br>9/11/20 - 6-10pm</a></li><br><br>


                        <li><a href='https://www.facebook.com/pages/category/Farmers-Market/Bellefonte-Farmers-Market-244701048977/'><b>Old Stone Cider&#126;</b><br>Lewisvillie PA<br>9/25/20 - 5:30-8:30pm</a></li>

                   </ul>
            </div>
      
      </main>
              
 
                <footer id='big-footer'>
           <h3 id='copyright'>copyright &copy;2020 sycamore alley</h3>
        
           <a href='https://www.facebook.com/sycamore.alley/' id='facebook-icon'><img src='images/facebook-sparkle.png'></a>
        
    </footer>

   
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS rule in your media query for > 992:

```
.gigs {
    display: none;
}
```

This also hides the `h1`...

Comment: Thanks! That fixed one problem, which was that the title style wasn't working on the gigs page, but the other problem is that I can no longer change the size of the h1 for >992.